# Asking recruiter to set me up with another position after being rejected?

Tags: interviewing, internship, rejection

I was supposed to interview for a big data platform engineer intern (as that is my expertise as of now) but wanted to get into full stack development so I interviewed for the full stack position instead.

On my third interview they rejected me. I was curious, is it ok to ask the recruiter to set up a interview up with the big data platform team in the company after being rejected from the full stack role?

The first recruiter I talked to said that we can get you started with a full stack development interview (since that is what I am interested in right now), but if that doesn't work out then we can reschedule an interview with the Big Data team. Any thoughts if I should do this or just send a appreciation email for their time?

**Clarification:**

- Both recruiters work for the company.
- The first recruiter told me that she can set me up with the Big Data team if the full stack doesn't work out. But for the full stack position I have been following up with the second recruiter (not the first) and I am wondering if I should ask the first or second recruiter regarding this? Since the first recruiter is sort of out of the loop as of now since I have talking to the second one when interviewing with the full stack role.

Comment: For clarification: Are the recruiters working for the company with which you are interviewing? Or are they with an external company? Also, to be clear, you have dealt with two different recruiters so far, and the first one said you can try for big data if full stack doesn't work? And now you want to follow up along those lines with the second recruiter?

Comment: @user1008090 Yes, exactly! They both work for the company. The first recruiter told me that she can set me up with the Big Data team if the full stack doesn't work out. But for the full stack position I have been following up with the second recruiter (not the first) and I am wondering if I should ask the first or second recruiter. Since the first recruiter is sort of out of the loop as of now since I have talking to the second one when interviewing with the full stack role.

Comment: By all means follow up. The difficulty is deciding on which recruiter. While it might not make a difference to you if you get a position with the company, it will make a huge difference to the recruiters in terms of who gets the commission. You might include both of them on your communications and ask them to decide with whom you should speak in order to follow up for the big data position.

Comment: @user Oh I didn't think about that commission part haha... Maybe I could email the second recruiter and mention that the first recruiter told me that she can set me up with the big data team. Or is that just adding more complexity?

Comment: Personally I would email both. That way everything is up front from this point forward and neither can claim backstabbing/client theft at a later time. Also, it absolves you of having to decide between the two.

Comment: @user Ok I will go ahead and include both of them in one email. Not email them separately correct? I also included a sample email, can you please take a quick look at it if possible?

Comment: I don't really see the problem here. They've already rejected you, what's the worst that can happen if you enquire about the other position? Although I do hope you're not thinking of asking the recruiter "to set up an interview", as if you have a right to have an interview set up, but rather ask them whether interviewing would be a possibility, or whether they'd be interested.

Comment: Yeah I did ask them to set it up. Can't do much now haha

Answer (score 1):

Making an answer of my comments:
Yes, you should follow up for the Big Data position. Contact both recruiters in the same email to avoid confusion or contention between them when you inquire about the BD position. They will either work together with you or one will clearly take over handling you. Good luck!

Comment: Once last thing haha... Does my sample email look good in my question above?

Comment: @ToothyRel I suggest you wait some time before accepting an answer. You only got this one so far, and users seeing bits already accepted tend to refrain from giving more answers (which is a loss for you and the community).